prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x^2}$ in $[-1,1]$ converges uniformly
i want to prove that the series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x^2}$ converges uniformly in $[-1,1]$, i have tried 2 approaches:

i tried to use weirstrass M test, but i end up with the conclusion that $\vert\frac{(-1)^n}{n+x^2}\vert\leq\frac{1}{n}$ which is not a convergent series.
second approach is using cauchy defenition: for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist N such that for every $m,m+p>N: \sum_{n=m+1}^{m+p} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x^2}\leq\sum_{n=m+1}^{m+p} \frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{p}{1+x^2}<p$. i dont know how to proceed after this and make it less than $\varepsilon$.

these are the only things i could think of considering every other theorem i know helps to disprove conergence. any help? also do you have any tips on how to approach these questions its harder than a number series since i cant calculate?

Hint: You should use Dirichlet test, here.

Im not used to to using dirichlet on function series only on number series. Does using it suffice for a proof? Does it prove pointwise or uniform convegrence?

There is a Dirichlet test for series of functions & it is a generalized version of Dirichlet series of Numbers

First note that the partial sums $$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n,$$ is uniformly bounded, and the sequence $(1/(n+x^2))_n$ is monotonically decreasing and $$\frac{1}{n+x^2}\to 0,$$ uniformly since for any $x\in [-1,1]$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+x^2}=0,$$ and$$||\frac{1}{n+x^2}-0||_\infty=\frac{1}{n}\to 0.$$ Then, the Dirichlet test implies that the series $$\sum a_n(x)b_n(x),$$ converges uniformly, where $a_n(x)=(-1)^n$ and $b_n(x)=\frac{1}{n+x^2}$.

We need to show that $f_n(y)=\sum_{q\geq n}(-1)^q/(n+y)$ converges uniformly to zero for $0\leq y=x^2\leq 1$ which holds by $|f_n(y)|\leq 1/(n+y)\leq 1/n\stackrel \infty \longrightarrow 0$, done

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

That looks similar to M test, but doesnt $\sum_{n=1}\infty \frac{1}{n}$ converge?

Diverge*** not converge
